# Hash function for words: How to find close matches

Tags: c, hashtable

I have a hashtable for words and I calculate the position like this:

```
int hash(char* word)
{
    int h = 0;
    int i ;
    int c = 42;
    for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(word) ; i++)
    {   
        h += mot[i] * pui(c, i);
    }
}
```

I calculate my position by adding each ascii to an integer and I multiply each ascii by the index at power of a constant.

But I want the closest matches inside my hashtable from a word that is not inside my hashtable without browsing all my hashtable. Should I modify my hash function to return a better position to put close words together?

Comment: You might want to consider encoding with Soundex or Metaphone, either instead of or before hashing. But one disadvantage of hashing is that proximity searches are hard.

Comment: If you want the closest match in an ordered set I'd say that a hash table is the wrong data structure. Use a sorted list or search tree instead.

Comment: If you replace the hash function with a soundex code evaluation function, proximity search will be pretty easy, although the hash might probably degenerate....